# Thunderbird and others acting strange under 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, software-center, thunderbird

This may be a bug report and, if so, I apologise for posting here but my problems seem to have a tangential similarity to various others reported here.

To give complete information:
A while back I moved my system to a new location, the effect was that I started to use WiFi connection instead of a wired connection. Even with the slower connection (down from 25Mbps to ~10Mbps) the system, 14.04, was running “perfectly”. I mention this as when I first started my adventures with Ubuntu I only had a WiFi connection and I had great difficulty with the initial installation (from a live CD created on a Windows system) which was cured by finally making a wired connection; I tentatively concluded that the WiFi driver on the CD was, in some way, deficient.

When the offer came to upgrade to 16.04.1 I accepted it. There were some problems (see below) so I downloaded the 16.04 ISO file and did a total reinstall. After the install I did (as I have done many times with total success) a total file restore before installing or using any packages. In theory I should have had the same configuration as after the upgrade. I installed my “extra” packages and tried it all out.

I had exactly the same problems as I had after the upgrade/before the reinstallation.

The problems I have:
(a) Thunderbird (in particular) is very slow to start but once running seems OK;
(b) Thunderbird is very slow to close down;
(c) An oddity, during the protracted shut-down - moving the cursor over the list of messages in a folder makes them disappear from the screen. On starting T’bird again, they are all reappear.
(d) First noticed in T’bird but later confirmed to happen with other packages (Firefox, gnuCash, KeePassX),  if the package is minimised for a long period (hours, but no real evidence on how many) it will not restore by clicking on the icon in the Launcher, the only thing that works is to right click the icon and Quit and then restart the package.
(e) After installing various packages (gnuCash, VLC) from the Software Centre and then closing and reopening the Software Centre  still only shows the Install button (even though the package may have been used). After rebooting the system and opening the Software Centre the Remove button is present.

Again, for completeness:
I have a modest number of add-ons in T’bird, the behaviour in (a), (b) and (c) doesn’t change if they are disabled or removed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your time and any help provided.

Eric

Comment: An update: I have done some more work on this. On a (completely) different hardware configuration under 16.04 T'bird's behaviour doesn't change at all. Reverting to 14.04 I have not observed the "freezing" of the minimised state but the blanking out of the email list is present. It's harder to see if I use a fast hard wired network connection rather than a (comparatively) slow WiFi connection.

Comment: However, I leave the new Software Centre problem/comment standing but I'm reluctant to flag it as a bug until someone else can provide confirmation. Can anyone?

Comment: So, to sum it up. You have graphical and system related performance issues on some applications depending on the speed of your network? WTH! Also, after clean install of 16.04, you overwrote the application and desktop environment settings in the hidden folders under /home/youruser with old version's files? If yes, those graphical glitches may be caused by that. Your best bet is create another user, delete your previous user, and don't overwrite those files again.

Comment: @eridani I wasn't very clear in my original post: I am NOT suggesting that the slow network link is the CAUSE of (c), I postulate that the behaviour is present in (my) T'bird and the slowness (reason unknown) of the shut down allows me to see it.     I have built a brand new 14.04 (on a different machine) and imported only my T'bird profile. The same behaviour (ie (c) above) occurs. I assume it's something in the profile and I am currently trying to get my emails (without the profile) from the old to the new machines to see if that removes the problem. I "can't" abandon my old email messages

Comment: I have rebuilt my T'bird profile "from scratch" (starting with a virgin T'bird installation and importing all emails, calendar events, tasks and contacts) (and I don't want to have to do it again!) and the strange behaviour is not observable ie: it may still be happening but the close down is so fast I can't see it happen. Thus, I'm going to accept that something had happened to my profile - no idea of what/when. Thanks to @eridani for the push that got me looking there.